# Issue with a C++ timer implementation using the thread header

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

I've been trying to implement a timer class similar to this https://vorbrodt.blog/2019/02/25/better-timer-class/. However it looks like the code in there doesn't work right out of the box in my env for some reason. I tried to rewrite this class but have encountered some issues.

```
//Main Timer.h

 
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include "event.h";

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class Timer {
    
    std::thread m_thread;
    manual_event m_event;
    std::chrono::nanoseconds m_tick;
    unsigned long long m_ticks = 0;

    struct internal_proc
    {
        std::function <bool(void)> proc;
        unsigned long long ticks;
        mutable unsigned long long elapsed;
        std::shared_ptr<manual_event> evt;
    };
    std::deque<internal_proc> event_queue;
public:
    template<typename T>
    Timer(T&& tick) :m_tick(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(tick)),  m_thread([this]() {
        std::cout << "Checking what is going on\n";
        
        auto realTimeStart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::nanoseconds drift{ 0 };

        while (!m_event.wait_for(1ms - drift)) {
        
            ++m_ticks;
            auto it = std::begin(event_queue);
            auto end = std::end(event_queue);

            while (it != end)
            {
                auto& event_obj = *it;
                ++event_obj.elapsed;
                if (event_obj.elapsed == event_obj.ticks)
                {
                    auto funcCalResult = event_obj.proc();
                    if (funcCalResult) {
                        event_queue.erase(it++);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        event_obj.elapsed = 0;
                    }
                }
                ++it;
            }

            auto realTimeEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto realExecTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(realTimeEnd - realTimeStart);
            auto progExecTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(1ms * m_ticks);
            drift = realExecTime - progExecTime;
        }
        }) {
    
    }

    template<typename T,typename F>
    auto setInterval(T&& interval,  F  f) {

        std::cout << "Check\n";
        auto manEvtObject = std::make_shared<manual_event>();
        auto proc = [=]() {
            if (manEvtObject->wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0))) return true;
            f();
            return false;
        };

    
        event_queue.push_front({proc,
            static_cast<unsigned long long>(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(interval).count() / m_tick.count()),
            0,
            manEvtObject
            });
    
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    return manEvtObject;
    
    }
    ~Timer() {
        std::cout << "Cheking data\n";
        m_event.signal();
        m_thread.join();
    }


};
```

```
// event.h
#pragma once

#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class manual_event
{
public:
    explicit manual_event(bool signaled = false) noexcept
        : m_signaled(signaled) {}

    void signal() noexcept
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
            m_signaled = true;
        }
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }

    void wait() noexcept
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_cv.wait(lock, [&]() { return m_signaled != false; });
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool wait_for(T t) noexcept
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        return m_cv.wait_for(lock, t, [&]() { return m_signaled != false; });
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool wait_until(T t) noexcept
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        return m_cv.wait_until(lock, t, [&]() { return m_signaled != false; });
    }

    void reset() noexcept
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_signaled = false;
    }

private:
    bool m_signaled = false;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
};

class auto_event
{
public:
    explicit auto_event(bool signaled = false)
        : m_signaled(signaled) {}

    void signal()
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
            m_signaled = true;
        }
        m_cv.notify_one();
    }

    void wait()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_cv.wait(lock, [&]() { return m_signaled != false; });
        m_signaled = false;
    }

    template<typename Rep, typename Period>
    bool wait_for(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& t)
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(m_mutex);
        bool result = m_cv.wait_for(lock, t, [&]() { return m_signaled != false; });
        if (result) m_signaled = false;
        return result;
    }

    template<typename Clock, typename Duration>
    bool wait_until(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& t)
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(m_mutex);
        bool result = m_cv.wait_until(lock, t, [&]() { return m_signaled != false; });
        if (result) m_signaled = false;
        return result;
    }

private:
    bool m_signaled = false;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
};
```

```
#include "Timer.h";
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
void testFunction(){
 std::cout<<"Hey"<<std::endl;
}
int main(){
 Timer t(1ms);
 auto e = t.setInterval(1ms,testFunction);
 e->signal();

}
```

From my understanding, the Timer constructor function (in timer.h) creates a thread and runs it. The function that the thread runs should process all the events in the event queue which is added to by the setInterval function, until the Timer destructor is called which raises a signal and joins the main thread, promptly exits out of the outer while loop. However, right now the **m_thread** will simply exit after a few ms unless I block the current thread by going to sleep in the **setInterval** function.

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
```

The setInterval function seems to work properly(callback fired every interval) for the duration of the block.  Is there  anything that I am missing from the article or my implementation? Thanks!

I am using the latest visual studio build if that helps!

Comment: Have you debugged your code at all?  Is anything unexpected happening to cause the loop to complete before you expected?

Comment: Off the top, there's a race. `m_thread` is constructed first, before other member variables like `m_event` or `event_queue`. The actual thread may start and access those members before they've been constructed.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 There doesn't seem to be errors when the loop exits early (exit code 0), the outer while loop seemingly exists right away, after printing the first statement unless I block the thread by putting it to sleep in setInterval

Comment: In `main`, `Timer` instance is created and then destroyed very quickly afterwards. It's possible that, by the time the thread starts up and gets to `while (!m_event.wait_for(1ms - drift)) {`, the event `m_event` is already signaled.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for commenting! I tried to place the object on the heap and don't call delete right away, though the issue still seems to occur. Its pretty strange like unless i block the current thread, it will execute the initial print and context switch back to the main thread right away.

Comment: If you don't destroy `Timer`, then you don't join the thread, and then nothing prevents `main` from quickly running to completion. When `main` returns (very quickly after starting), the program terminates; all threads still running are killed.